# How to change playback speed of videos on Facebook or other platforms

Tags: facebook

When watching videos on Facebook or other platforms, I sometimes want to speed the video up but there is no option to do so.

How do I change the play back speed of a Facebook or other platform video?

EDIT: This is a programming related question... see the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I have figured out how to do this, is to modify the DOM.

I use the HTML source inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I on Firefox) and go to the INSPECTOR tab and I look for the VIDEO tag and look for the ID of this tag.

So for example it might look like this:

```
<video id="u_0_66" bla bla bla
```

So the id of this video is `u_0_66`

I then click on the CONSOLE tab, and there is a spot at the bottom for you type, so type the following:

```
document.getElementById("u_0_66").playbackRate = 1.25;
```

You can change the playback to whatever you want like slowing it down to half speed 0.5 or speeding it up to double speed 2.0, with 1.0 being normal playback speed.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome, open developer tools (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>), click next to the little `>` (this will let you enter some javascript).

Now enter:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 2
```

That selects the *top* video on screen. If you're after the second or third (etc), simply adjust the number in square brackets

```
// second video
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].playbackRate = 2
```

```
// third video
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[2].playbackRate = 2
```

If you want it fast than double speed, simply change the value like so (this is for triple speed):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 3
```